# Catching javascript exceptions in all browser

Tags: javascript, jsp, exception, try-catch

I have a jsp file including an inline javascript who throws an error when the adblock module is active in Firefox. The error impact essential features of my web page.

I know the problem and how to solve it but i can't modify the jsp file because i can't build and delivery a new EAR.
I just can modify an external javascript file called by my webpage.

So, my question is : how to catch all javascript errors triggered in my web page and ensure that it crashes my page ? 
I would like the clients do not meet the js error simply, this is why I would like to catch.

p.s : excuse me if my english is not perfect but i hope you understand my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your file loaded before or after the javascript code from hat JSP page?

Comment: Please explain how your jsp file is included, and when its code gets run. Without knowledge of when and how the code runs, we can't offer useful help or advice.